# Infomatica Row Count

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

I am new to Informatica and I am confused.

I have data from a flat file and need to do some transformation for it. I just need a general idea on how to actually do it.

Say I have data that looks like this:

COL1, COl2, COl3, COL4

A B C D

A B B B

G G G G

B D D X

F F F F

B B A D

1) I need to transfer only rows that have the first column as A or B

2) I need the count of the rows that are A, and I need a separate count that is B

3) I need a comparison of the count of A and the count of B. If the count do not match then I need an email sent.

Can someone give me a link to something helpful or tell me exactly that types of transformation / logic I should be using? Thanks

Comment: For 1st question you can use `DECODE` in `EXPRN transformation` then filter with `filter transfrmn` , 2nd and 3rd are not clear, can you provide sample output for each question ?

Comment: Count of all rows with COL1 having A in the beginning. Count of all rows with COL1 having B in the beginning. After the counts are made if they are equal than output to a flat file, if they are not equal then send email.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways. Here's a simple one, step-by-step.

1. Use a filter on `Source Qualifier` to get just the data you need.
2. Separate into two pipelines using `Router Transformation` with two groups defined as `COL1='A'` and `COL1='B'`
3. Use `Aggregate Transformation` to get the counts (for each pipeline).
4. Use `Expression Transformaiton` to add a dummy port e.g. `joinPort = 1` (for each pipeline).
5. Join the piplelines on dummy port using `Joiner Transformation`
6. Use `Expression Transformation` to compare the results.

Sending email a separate story.

1. Use a Workflow variable e.g. wfSendEmail initialized to 0 and a mapping variable e.g. mSendEmail
2. On session `Components tab` do the `Pre-session variable assignment` and assign wfSendEmail to mSendEmail.
3. In the exression transformation mentioned in p.6 above use the `SETVARIABLE` function if the counts do not match to set the mSendEmail to `1`.
4. On session `Components tab` do the `Post-session variable assignment` and assign mSendEmail value to wfSendEmail.
5. Add and `Email task` with a condition `wfSendEmail=1` on the link from the session.

Comment: Okay, I am going to make an attempt at this. Thanks.